# Android Sherlock Actionbar newbie

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've just installed sherlock actionbar into my app
, but I want to know how to use it ?

I mean how to put a next button, or the drop down menu, etc ..

searched around didn't get a good result, all what I got was how to install it which is easy, any guides on how to put a next button or a drop down menu etc .. ?

Comment: The download comes with a ton of demos; start there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use ActionBarSherlock you should first learn the built-in action bar API that is available on API 14. ActionBarSherlock is simply a backport of the native action bar API.

Here are some good resources:

- [`ActionBar` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)
- [`Fragment` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
- ["Using The Action Bar"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)
- ["Creating Menus"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)
- ["Using the v4 Library APIs"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Using)

Answer (score 1):

There should be example projects that come with it or are available on the site.  I learned just by looking at the code provided in those, and they are complete projects that you can load on your phone to see how they look.

Comment: when I try to use them on my phone. Eclipse says u cant run libraries